# How do I publish a custom React hook written in Typescript to npm?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-hooks

I have written a React hook in Typescript and would like to publish it to npm, but I can't seem to get the build configuration correct. I'm not using any other build tool besides `tsc`. I have read the recommendations in the Typescript docs, React docs, and a few blog posts.

I don't get any errors when I build and publish, but when I try to import the module in another project I get an error importing React. Yet everything I've ready suggests that `react` should be a `peerDependency` when publishing custom hooks.

> Cannot find module 'react' from '../useMyHook/build/index.js'

- tsc: `v4.1.3`
- react: `v16.14.0`

Repo: https://github.com/raineorshine/use-swipe-to-dismiss

**tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "./build"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

**package.json** (abbreviated):

```json
{
  "name": "useMyHook",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "files": [
    "build/**/*"
  ],
  "main": "build",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.0.0",
    "typescript": ">=4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.21",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0"
  }
}
```

**index.ts** (abbreviated):

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

const useMyHook = () => {

  const [x, setX] = useState<number>(0)

  return {
    onClick: () => {
      console.log(x)
    }
  }
}

export default useMyHook
```

Comment: Do the contents of your `build` folder contain everything that you would expect?  A combination of .d.ts and .js files?  You might need to include `"noEmit": false` in your tsconfig but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: checkout my repo, im using typescript and its a react package on npm. 

https://github.com/EliHood/materialui-gif-textbox, hopefully the codebase can provide some idea.

Comment: @LindaPaiste: Build folder contains `index.js` and `index.d.ts`. Unfortunately `"noEmit": false` does not help.

Comment: @BARNOWL: Thank you, but your repo is a Component not a Hook. It includes `react` as a dependency so it doesn't run into the same error trying to publish with `react` as a `peerDependency`.

Comment: In my case I could import your npm package from another react project without running into any issue.